# Android image rotate via xml file

Tags: android, xml

I've been attempting to make a image file rotate on the spot and am struggling, every tutorial I find seems to do this in a different way.

Can someone point where I'm going wrong here.

GamePlay.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class GamePlay extends Activity {

 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
 @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.gameplay);

 ImageView logo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mainlogo);
 logo.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.rotate);

 AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) logo.getBackground();

 frameAnimation.start();

 }
}
```

rotate.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:pivotX="50%" 
android:pivotY="50%" 
android:fromDegrees="0"
android:toDegrees="360" 
android:drawable="@drawable/logo" />
```

gameplay.xml

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/mainlogo"
    android:src="@drawable/logo">       
</ImageView>
```

Comment: Image rotation you say? I would load it as a texture in OpenGL and then use the normal Open GL rotate commands to do what your xml said. I would also use the Simple XML Framework to parse the XML in the first place.

Comment: In rotate.xml wich should be located in `res/anim` you should add some attributes like: `android:repeatCount="infinite"` and `android:duration="1200"`

Comment: I think it is rotating, but since you have no `android:duration=""` it doesn't last enough to be seen.

Answer (score 1):

Change rotate.xml to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <rotate
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1200"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:toDegrees="360" />
 </set>
```

place it in res/anim/ folder

and try this to start animation

```
ImageView logo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.mainlogo);
Animation rotateAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
            R.anim.rotate);
logo.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code; it works for me:

```
ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.snoopy);
// Getting width & height of the given image.
int w = bmp.getWidth();
int h = bmp.getHeight();
// Setting post rotate to 90
Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
mtx.postRotate(90);
// Rotating Bitmap
Bitmap rotatedBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, w, h, mtx, true);
BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(rotatedBMP);

img.setImageDrawable(bmd);

}
```

Comment: There is something wrong with your braces... In particular, you're missing the opening one.