# how to rotate multiple images in android with overlay on eachother in XML code?

Tags: android, image, rotation

I want to display the roating images like the below shown in image one by one. How can i code in xml. I could not able to rotate image using android:rotation="20". I have to display the images like shown in image with the one on one from left to right.

[image]

Comment: Take a look here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6024113/android-image-rotate-via-xml-file

Comment: thanks but i need to rotate in XML. not by code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:fromDegrees="90"
        android:toDegrees="90"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:drawable="@drawable/image">
</rotate>
```

Make sure your `android:fromDegrees` is correct.

Comment: should i have to put this for all the cards?

Comment: Yes, for each imageview you should put all of the android: things in

Comment: should i have to put this in backgroud of ImageView

Comment: try using the code above without the xmlns: and use the code above to create your card's images

Comment: how to use it on imageview?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Rotate {

public static Bitmap rotate(Bitmap src, float degree) {
    // create new matrix
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // setup rotation degree
    matrix.postRotate(degree);

    // return new bitmap rotated using matrix
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It will be better to write method, and write in it RotateAnimation code, and pass the parameters accordingly to rotate each and every image.